# Шаблон конструктора в javascript

Tags: javascript

Создать конструктор можно двумя способами:

```
Global = function (){
 /* */
}
```

**и**

```
function Global(){
  /* */
}

var object = new Global();
```

Есть ли принципиальное отличие в этих шаблонах?

Comment: new Global(); // ok
    function Global(){}

****

    new Global(); // error, Global is not defined
    var Global = function(){};

Comment: @AlexWindHope, ну это как бы известно, поэтому в постановке вопроса я написал инициализацию объекта ПОСЛЕ объявления конструктора. Стало быть разницы в шаблонах нет.

Comment: Первый пример - именованная функция, видна везде (в смысле и до и после объявления).

Второй пример - анонимная функция и доступна только после объявления. 

На javascript.ru всё прекрасно расписано.

Кстати, в первом примере функция `Global` будет находится в глобальной области видимости.

Comment: @lampa не в глобальной а в любой текущей или предыдущей где есть var Glabal.

Comment: @lampa, во втором примере функция Global также будет в глобальной области видимости.

Comment: @eicto В том-то и дело, что ключевого слова var нет :)
А так да, вы правы

Comment: я имею ввиду, что неправильно говорить глобальная область видимости, т.к. мы не знаем что является родительской областью видимости для этого кода.

Comment: вот например

    (function (Global) {
        Global = function () {
            /* */
        };
        console.log(1, Global); //1,function(){}
    })();
    console.log(2, Global); //Global is not defined